# How do I get the value of a textview in an Adapter?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I created an adapter with a textview inside of it, and I passed the Textview to my voting method, the as shown below, however, the response I get back is the name of the textview not the value of the textview. How do I fix this?

```
 class ViewDashboard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView question;

    public ViewDashboard(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        questionText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionText);

        Voting s=new Voting();
    s.Like(getAdapterPosition(),ViewpagerAdapter.this,questionId);
```

Voting Class

```
 public void Like(final int position,final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, TextView textViewId){
   //the questionId, that we pass in is a textview, therefore, we need to convert it to a String
   final String stringId=textViewId.getText().toString();
```

Comment: s.Like(getAdapterPosition(),ViewpagerAdapter.this,questionId); change it to s.Like(getAdapterPosition(),ViewpagerAdapter.this, questionText);

Comment: that did not work, instead, I got the text, to which I orginally set the Textview to, in the layout to, not the data that was passed through it